# Как классу модели ссылаться на самого себя (ManyToManyField)?

Tags: python, django

Допустим, у меня есть класс фильм (Film), и так как на всех сайтах кинотеатров, когда вы заходите на интересующий вас фильм, вам доступно поле с рекомендациями (похожие фильмы), класс Film должен ссылаться на массив объектов самого себя.

```
class Film(models.Model):
    recommend_films = models.ManyToManyField(Film, blank=True)
```

Ошибка: *Undefined variable: "Film"*.

Так как мне реализовать данный функционал???

Comment: Используйте `'self'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решением данной проблемы будет заключение названия класса в кавычки

```py
class Film(models.Model):
    recommend_films = models.ManyToManyField('Film', blank=True)
```